FastAPI and aioboto3: Streaming Download
I would like to use an API endpoint as a proxy for streaming a file to the client. I am using FastAPI, as well as aioboto3.
Currently, the implementation of the endpoint looks like this:
@app.get('/s3/{file_name:path}')
async def file_proxy(file_name: str):
    async with session.client('s3', { config }):
        file = await s3.get_object(Bucket='bucket-name', Key=file_name)
        return StreamingResponse(content=file['Body'].iter_chunks())

The issue is this will await and block the function until the entire file is finished downloading. But, instead of this, I want to download and stream the file continuously, in chunks of n MiB, for example. How can I do this?

I found Range parameter in the documentation which might be helpful here. So, it should look something like this I guess:
CHUNK_LENGTH_MB = 10


async def get_file_chunk(bucket_name: str, key: str, chunk_length: int) -> AsyncGenerator[bytes, None]:
    """Async generator to get file chunk."""

    async with session.client("s3", { config }):
        head = await s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key)
        content_length = head["ContentLength"]

        for offset in range(0, content_length, chunk_length):
            end = min(offset + chunk_length - 1, content_length - 1)
            s3_file = await s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=key, Range=f"bytes={offset}-{end}")

            async with s3_file["Body"] as stream:
                yield await stream.read()


@app.get("/s3/{file_name:path}")
async def file_proxy(file_name: str):
    chunk_length = CHUNK_LENGTH_MB * 1024 * 1024  # Convert to bytes
    file_chunk_iterator = get_file_chunk(bucket_name="bucket-name", key=file_name, chunk_length=chunk_length)

    return StreamingResponse(content=file_chunk_iterator)

